# I added a script to /etc/rc.local and now ubuntu doesn't start

Tags: server, startup

So, I was trying to make my Java app to run at startup, and I added it to `/etc/rc.local`. The problem is that the app runs continuously and now the system start just hangs on there. Is there any way to recover from that or did I completely mess it up?

Comment: **Please do not use obscenities in your posts.** Note that other users may have flagged your post as **rude or abusive** leading to possible rep loss or suspension. Please [Be Nice](https://askubuntu.com/help/be-nice): *Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `&` after the command. For example, `java -jar myapp.jar &`

The `&` detaches the program from the terminal, allowing it to run in the background.

---

As for recovering from it, try editing it from recovery mode. If that doesn't work, you can use a live USB drive to edit it.